# changing the spacing for a bar chart in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I would like to eliminate the empty space that is shown below in an oval , i.e the space between the y axis and
the bar (blue bar). Is there a way I can do it ? I dont seem to find any properties on the chart to alter it ..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by going to Horizontal axis properties----->Axis options----->Set the side margins disabled.